# Best way to paint Ikea metal brackets?

Tags: paint, metal

I'd like to paint in white my Ikea shelves's brackets ([described](https://www.ikea.com/gb/en/p/bergshult-granhult-wall-shelf-white-nickel-plated-s69290808/) thus: Aluminium, Nickel-plated, Clear acrylic lacquer).

What would be the best (but hopefully cheap) route in terms of products I need to buy for this job?

[image]

Comment: Product recommendations are off topic, I would probably sand and coat with a metal spray paint that matches what you want.

Comment: After painting, you can bake your metal pieces for an hour or so at 150F and get a better finish.

Comment: Many spray metal paints do not require primer with properly prepared surfaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Prep is the key

You can make it look good for 3 months with a rattle can.  If you want it to look good for 10 years, paint prep is called for.  Prep has 2 components: de-gloss(microscopically roughen) the surface so paint can bind to it, and cleaning the surface to remove contaminants.

**A 3M Scotchbrite pad**, green pots and pans style, for scuffing the surface to remove gloss. Even if it doesn't seem glossy now, give it a rub.  The objective is to degloss the chrome surface, *not* blow through to the aluminum layer.

**Common bathroom alcohol** e.g. Isopropyl, with a double cloth wipe, to remove contaminants.

**Rattle-can spray primer** such as Rustoleum 7779 rusty metal primer.  Take the time to learn to apply paint competently.

Nickel and aluminum are a challenging surface for Rusto metal primer, but I gather a mil-spec aluminum primer (the green stuff on unfinished airplanes) is out of the budget.  (It doesn't come in cans because it's 2-part; you mix the 2 parts minutes before you apply it.  Also, the B-part is toxic until it cures, so, not a thing they want in the consumer marketplace.

**Rattle-can spray paint** for your paint layer.

Comment: Thanks a lot, no chance I can get away with skipping the primer step as suggested by Ed Beal's comment above, or will such omission make the paint start peeling away after a while or something?

Comment: @drake035 Well I'd *much* rather you skip primer than skip prep!!!!!  But skipping primer is always a dice roll. I've got a job right now where I'm overcoating some plated steel, and I skipped primer on the first 12 pieces and it's chipping off from handling.  Switching to primer for the last 6 which means 4 coats since holidays are a huge problem on these intricate pieces.  As for the 12 already done, I don't look forward to sandblasting off all the failing paint.  That's the trouble with shortcuts *with paint*; the cost of redoing work is **painful**.